# Matlab GUI: Do I need to pass hObject AND handles?

Tags: matlab, handle, matlab-guide

I am fairly new to writing GUIs in Matlab and noticed that when passing information between callbacks usually two values `hObject` and `handles` are passed.

From what I read and understood, `hObject` is the handle to an object which contains the real data (or at least handles to it) and `handles` is not itself a handle, but a struct reproducing the structure of objects "behind" `hObject`. Changing (or adding to) `handles` does not change the real data as it is seen from the calling function but a local copy. To actually write the changed data into the object pointed to by `hObject` I need to call `guidata(hObject, handles)`.

Is this right so far or did I get something wrong?

I also read that I can create struct similar to `handles` by calling `handles = guidata(hObject)`.

**So is there any point in passing both `hObject` and `handles` to one of my own functions instead of just passing `hObject` and creating `handles` locally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct so far. The input parameter `handles` is a handy way of keeping track of all the components of the UI. As a standard `handles` is not an input parameter. But if you use `guide` it will set is as an extra parameter as follows by setting for example the `Callback` option to the anonymous function `@(hObject,eventdata)guitest('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))`.
This can of course just as easily be done in the code for the function by `handles = guidata(hObject)`.

Usually you will not need to change in the `handles` (only in the objects they refer to), but if you need to change something in the `handles` (for example if you use it to store more than just the `handles` for the UI elements) it is important to call `guidata(hObject, handles)` to actually save the changes.

So the short answer to you question is: no, you can just as well retrieve the `handles` yourself when you need them.